# Cannot add plugin to gradle build file?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm new to Gradle, but really having difficulty switching from Maven.

I try to follow [this guide](https://github.com/sherter/google-java-format-gradle-plugin) to add the Google formatter to my build.

Ideally, I want to check to see if the code is formatted correctly every time someone runs gradle build. I've tried the following strategy. It's not working out too well. Does this look like a well designed gradle file and how can I get this google formatter to work with it?

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.sherter.google-java-format:google-java-format-gradle-plugin:0.6"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.github.sherter.google-java-format'

group = 'com.remindful'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')
    compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session-core')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.5.RELEASE")
    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.4.191")

    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'
}

task format(type: GoogleJavaFormat) {
    source 'src/main'
    source 'src/test'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/*Template.java'
}

task verifyFormatting(type: VerifyGoogleJavaFormat) {
    source 'src/main'
    include '**/*.java'
    ignoreFailures true
}

// To force debug on application boot, switch suspend to y
bootRun {
    systemProperties System.properties
    jvmArgs=["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the appropriate tasks — `format` and `verifyFormatting` — but you have not incorporated them into the build. So, you should be able to run

`./gradlew format`

and

`./gradlew verifyFormatting`

but `./gradlew build` will not perform any formatting or verification of that.

First thing you need to decide is when you want these tasks to run. I would leave `format` as a manual step, i.e. someone should explicitly run that task in order to format their code. In which case, you do nothing, since `./gradlew format` should already work.

On the other hand, `verifyFormatting` should always run for a full build. Maven gets you to attach such tasks to a specific *phase*, but that's not the model Gradle uses. Instead, it works with a task graph in which tasks depend on one another. Your goal is to insert the `verifyFormatting` task into that graph in a suitable place.

Given that, the second thing to do is attach `verifyFormatting` to the appropriate task. This will depend on your requirements, but in this specific case I recommend the `check` task that's provided by the [Base Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/base_plugin.html#sec:base_tasks). This plugin is applied automatically by the Java Plugin and many others, so it's usually available.

The `check` task already depends on the `test` task, so it's the perfect place. Simply add this to your build script:

```
task verifyFormatting(...) {
    ...
}
check.dependsOn verifyFormatting
```

Note that the `build` task already depends on `check`, so `./gradlew build` will now also run `verifyFormatting`.

Comment: hm, I see Could not get unknown property 'GoogleJavaFormat' for root project. Great explanation, unfortunately, the task looks like it is giving me issues.

Comment: Added to build script and got A problem occurred evaluating root project 'core'.
> Could not get unknown property 'VerifyGoogleJavaFormat' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.

Comment: ./gradlew format doesnt even work by itself actually

Comment: Either use the fully-qualified class names for the custom task types or import them. Gradle only supports unqualified class names for core task types, i.e. those provided with Gradle itself.